# Why does GNU ld default linker script NOT have 'MEMORY'?

Tags: linker, gnu, ld, linker-scripts

I checked the output of `ld --verbose` on both x86_64 as well as on armv7l (beaglebone black rev C). The default linker script does not contain 'MEMORY' command. Why is that?

Comment: Same here. Have you found an answer? In my case `MEMORY` leads to [`ld: internal error ../../ld/ldlang.c 6101`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74616055/1778275). No ideas.