# Why processing of ld script leads to internal error ../../ld/ldlang.c 6101?

Tags: ld

Compiling this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char code[] __attribute__((section(".mySection"))) = "\xb8\x0d\x00\x00\x00\xc3";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int val = ((int(*)(void))code)();
    printf("val %d\n", val);
}
```

together with this ld script:

```
MEMORY
{
  my_region (RWX) : ORIGIN = 0x405340, LENGTH = 4K
}

SECTIONS
{
  .mySegment 0x405340 : {KEEP(*(.mySection))} > my_region
}
```

as:

```
gcc link.ld t79.c
```

leads to:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: link.ld contains output sections; did you forget -T?
/usr/bin/ld: internal error ../../ld/ldlang.c 6101
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why? How to fix?

```
ld version: 2.34
gcc version: 9.4.0
uname -a:
Linux xxx 5.15.0-25-generic #25~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 08:31:42 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

UPD: the `internal error ../../ld/ldlang.c 6101` comes from here (function `lang_size_relro_segment_1`):

```
ASSERT (desired_end >= seg->base);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `internal error ../../ld/ldlang.c 6101` comes from `RWX`. I was mistakenly thinking that `W` stands for "write", while `W` stands for "[read/write](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/MEMORY.html)".

In case of `WX` the output is the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: link.ld contains output sections; did you forget -T?
/usr/bin/ld: error: no memory region specified for loadable section `.interp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Instead of fixing it I use [GCC exploit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11645956/1778275):

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char code[]
__attribute__((section(".mySection,\"awx\"#"))) /* GCC exploit */
= "\xb8\x0d\x00\x00\x00\xc3";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int val = ((int(*)(void))code)();
    printf("val %d\n", val);
}

$ gcc t79.c && ./a.out
val 13
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve but the direct way to solve this problem would be:

1. At first use option `-T` to order the linker script to be read. That will lead you to the real problem.
2. Use option `-nostartfiles`, so together `gcc -T link.ld t79.c -nostartfiles`, to get rid of the undefined references, as the standard system startup files than won't be used when linking. The standard system libraries will be used normally.
3. Remove the `SECTIONS` part from the linker script to avoid collisions of `.mySegment` with the other sections.

After this kind of a brute force solution the program will be compiled and linked successfully, you'll get a printout -- I get a `val 13` -- and than the program will crash due to a segmentation fault.